# Cloning HD in SSD

Tags: snow-leopard, ssd, carbon-copy-cloner

I have an old Mac that I’d like to upgrade by adding an SSD.

The problem is that the OS is really old (Snow Leopard, Mac Early 2008), so I’m really not sure if is the backup restore is going to work.

So I thought I could carbon copy the current hard disk to a new SSD and boot from the SSD.

Do you see any problem in this approach?

Comment: iMac, Mac Pro (or MacBook Pro/MacBook which aren't really sold as an "Early 2008" model)?

Comment: @klanomath - Umm...  there's an [Early 2008 iMac](http://bit.ly/2ClO1Zx) and an [Early 2008 (white) MacBook](http://bit.ly/2GqWKao)...or am I mis-reading your question to the OP?

Comment: @klanomath early 2008 (white) MacBook. Does it really matter?

Comment: @Allan I only listed ["all 2008" models](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2008.html) with the iMac and MacPro (in fact it's the XServe - I have to drink another coffee ;-)) appearing as "early" models and didn't take a closer look to each model...

Comment: @ff8mania The "cloning" isn't really the problem here - it's rather the compatibility of the new SSD with the old Mac...

Comment: @klanomath - Yes.  Coffee.  I know ***exactly*** what you're referring to.

Comment: @klanomath I remember I looked some time ago and the common Samsung SSD should work

Comment: @klanomath both Crucials and Samsung models are available for the MacBook early 2008. Any suggestion or detail I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem cloning your old drive to a new SSD.  Cloning will make an exact copy of the drive, so other than being solid state rather than rotational, there's no difference

The one thing that you will want to do after you get your MacBook up and running is [enable TRIM support](http://www.mactrast.com/2011/07/how-to-enable-trim-support-for-all-ssds-in-os-x-lion/).  TRIM is the ATA command set that will "recycle" the deleted space on your SSD.  TRIM marks the deleted space as "unused" so that your OS will write to it again.

Comment: Thanks @Allan. do you suggest any software in particular for this job (according to my OS?)

Comment: I would use `dd` rather than pay for something.  `dd if=/dev/diskX of=/dev/diskY bs=1m` where X is your source disk and Y is your target.  You can get this info from `diskutil list`.